# How Many Possible NBA playoff brackets?

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification

**Important Information**

The NBA playoffs is a series in basketball to determine the NBA champions. $16$ teams play in a $4$ round (round of $16$,quarter-finals,semi-finals, finals) tournament, where teams compete each round in a best-of-seven series. The first team to win $4$ games wins the series. It is therefore possible to play as few as $4$ games or as many as $7$. The bracket of the $2016$ tournament is given [here](http://www.nbaplayoffsbracket.com/2016/index.php) to illustrate how the tournament works.

**The Question**

How many possible NBA playoffs brackets are there?

**My Work**

This process can be broken into multiple stages: choose the round-of-16 winners, the quarter finals winners, the semi-finals winners and the finals winners. Each series can involve the losing team winning $1,2$ or $3$ games.

*Losing Team Wins 1*

The losing team winning 1 is the number of ways to insert an L into the following sequence of W's _W_W_W_W. There are four ways to do this.

*Losing Team Wins 2*

The number of ways this can happen is the number of ways one can arrange 2 L's and 4 W's in such a way that an L never appears after 4 W's have appeared. This can be computed by letting $T = $ the total number of ways to arrange 4 W's and 2 L's $= \frac{6!}{4!2!}$ and letting $F =$ the  number of forbidden arrangements where an L appears after 4 W's. There are two sub cases here:

*One L appears after 4 W's*

One L appearing after 4 W's is simply adding an L to the end of our first case so there are many ways to do this. Therefore there are 4 ways to do this.

*Two L's appear after 4 W's*

This simply adding two L's to the end of the 4 W's. There is exactly one way to do this WWWWLL.

*Three L's appear after 4 Losses*

There is exactly one way to do this WWWWLLL

Therefore, by rule of sum, there are $4+5+1 = 10$ ways for a team to win the series. This means there are 20 ways overall for either team to win a series. There are $8$ series in the first round, $4$ series in the quarter finals, $2$ series in the  semis and $1$ series in the finals. By rule of product, there are $20^{8+4+2+1} = 20^{15}$ ways to win a series.

**My Research**

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213955/permutation-of-nba-playoffs) MSE question unfortunately did not go into enough depth for me because it didn't include series results, just who won the series

**My Problem**

I'm looking to see if I have done this correctly, and secondly to see if there is a more simple and elegant solution than what I did.

Comment: You might consider ${3\choose 0}$, ${4\choose 1}$, ${5\choose 2}$, ${6\choose 3}$ as the number of ways of losing a round but winning a particular number of games: they add up to ${7\choose 4}$, which is not $20$.  Perhaps double this since either team could win a series. Then take your powers

Comment: Don't forget, each conference plays amongst themselves - i.e., before the finals, there cannot be, say, a Spurs-Celtics series.

Comment: @Henry nice solution and it also pointed out a lot of steps I missed in my solution. Thanks for the helpful comment!